# Flask- mediapipe installation in heroku server

Tags: python, socket.io, mediapipe

I able to run the python flask code in heroku server successfully without error.

But if i add a statement "import mediapipe" library, its results with error.
even i have added all lines in APTFILE, even though im not abe to solve error,

libGL.so.1: how to clear this error.

and i have already added libsm6
libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
libgl1-mesa-glx
libglu1
libgl1-mesa-dev
libexample
these line in my APTFILE

please help me to solve this issue

libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
libgl1-mesa-glx
libglu1
libgl1-mesa-dev
libexample
these line in my APTFILE

Even though I'm not able to solve the error

Comment: Please add the error output to your question. Also double check that the Python package you added to your imports is availble on the Heroku server. Do this by adding all of your Python dependencies to a `requirements.txt` (e.g. `pip-freeze > requirements.txt`) file as documented here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#install-app-dependencies-locally